# cURL Authentication Issue

Tags: php, curl

below is the code that I try to login on the site. I do not know what does not work, the site probably changed something and that I do not work for me. I have no idea what could be.

```
$var = file_get_contents("http://www.dauanunt.ro/cont/login");

$q = explode("name=\"q\" value=\"",$var);
$q = explode("\" />",$q[1]);
$q = $q[0];

$ga_bi['a'] =  'login';
$ga_bi['q'] =  $q;
$ga_bi['h'] =  '';
$ga_bi['u'] =  'gabrielaromania66@gmail.com';
$ga_bi['p'] =  'testing';
$ga_bi['r'] =  '1';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.dauanunt.ro/cont/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.dauanunt.ro");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ga_bi);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any coding error.  It looks like the website you are trying to login is adding extra steps during the login.

http://www.dauanunt.ro/c/login5.js